# How to create a foldable NSLog-Output using Swift?

Tags: swift, console, itunes, nslog

Is it possible to create a foldable `NSLog`-Output using `Swift`?
Below I added a screenshot showing the `iTunes`-Logs on `Console`-application.

[image: Foldable <code>NSLog</code>-Output]

How to create this foldable output?

Answer (score 0):

I just made some more researches with different terms.
I came to the result that the used technique for this kind of logging is named `Activity Tracing`.

Advanced References:

- [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/activity-tracing/#activity-tracing-and-swift) (detailed explanation and basics)
- [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/activity_tracing) (an - in my opinion - official plain
  documentary; `Objective-C`-documentary provides more content than the documentary for `Swift`)
- [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/714/) (WWDC 2014 Session Introduction)
- [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) (WWDC 2016 Session about Logging Techniques in general, including `Activity Tracing`)
- [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Logging/Introduction/Intro.html) (Sample Code for Logging using `os_log`-APIs)

This might be helpful for others with a similar upcoming question.